# c++ Structure Arrays - "This declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, struct

I'm having trouble with struct arrays. this is the code I have that produces 2 red error lines.

```
    struct frequents
{
    int count;
    char letter;
};

frequents testArray[2];
testArray[1].letter = 'v';
```

The error appears under testArray which has the declaration error and under '.' which mentions that it expected a ';'.

Comment: Code compiles fine here. Well, once you put it into a function.

Comment: @Ron The function that is missing from the code in the question

Comment: @Ron Doesn't matter. That code needs to live in a function of some form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I always felt your intellect and drive would be better entertained with C++. I wonder why you still haven't made the switch from Delphi? Plenty to explore in the C++ realm.

Comment: @Ron A million lines of code are holding me back........ Not that I am a massive fan of C++. I find it to have more complexity that I like. I do like the fact that C++ compilers tend to produce faster code than the useless Delphi compiler. Flip side though, as a Win32 programmer, I think VCL is still way ahead of anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not in a function: replace

```
testArray[1].letter = 'v';
```

by

```
int main() {
    testArray[1].letter = 'v';
    return 0;
}
```

and it compiles allright.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements):

```
testArray[1].letter = 'v';
```

Statements are to be executed inside functions (function body) and not in some arbitrary global namespace as you have it now. Move your statement inside a main program [entry point function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function), a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), a free standing [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions) or a [class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) member function body.

Alternatively, use the [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to initialize your array:

```
frequents testArray[2] = {{ 1, 'a' }, { 2, 'b' }};
```

or without the extra braces:

```
frequents testArray[2] = { 1, 'a', 2, 'b' };
```